# Rails Dependent Form Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am using the [dependent fields rails gem](https://github.com/vollnhals/dependent-fields-rails) and [this video tutorial](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/dependent-form-fields) to try to implement a dependent field in my user signup form. My signup form has a field where the user can select their role (implemented using enums). I want the university field to be hidden by default and only appear if the user selects "staff" as their role. The current behavior is that all the form fields are visible upon load. What am I doing wrong? Any help for a newb would be greatly appreciated! I've read other SO questions but can't seem to get this to work.

Here's my form:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :role %>
      <%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.map {|role| [role.titleize,role]}, :include_blank => "Please Select")  %>

      <%= content_tag :div, class: 'js-dependent-fields', data: { 'data-select-id': 'user_role', 'data-option-value': 'staff'} do %>
      <%= f.label :university_id%>
      <%= collection_select( :user, :university_id, University.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the lower part of my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require dependent-fields
//= require_tree .

 $(document).ready(function() {
     DependentFields.bind()
 });
```

Comment: Does you browser console show any JS errors? Did you call `DependentFields.bind()` on `$(document).ready(...)`?

Comment: My browser console shows nothing. I'm adding my application.js to the original question.

Comment: I also have underscore.js in vendor/assets/javascripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the cause, but your data attribute is appending an extra "data-" block I believe:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: 'js-dependent-fields', data: { 'data-select-id': 'user_role', 'data-option-value': 'staff'} do %>
  vv
<%= content_tag :div, class: 'js-dependent-fields', data: { 'select-id': 'user_role', 'option-value': 'staff'} do %>
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks Andrew!

Comment: Oh sweet! No problem. Vote for my answer :)